# php getting two integers from a string then apply a multiply operation

Tags: php

I have a POS system with the following product naming convention ("Product Thickness" + "Product Name" + "Product Size"), examples of products:-

- 10MM BRONZE FLOAT 321*225
- 10MM CLEAR FLOAT 366*244
- 10MM CLEAR FLOAT 321*225

How can i get the product "Product Size" from the product string then multiply the product height with width (eg. 321 x 225) ?

Comment: You could use a regex to get the two numbers, then cast them to an integer and multiply them afterwards. [Here's an example regex](https://regex101.com/r/1ZMe8m/1) for starters.

Comment: If you are going to resolve the question in a comment, why not resolve the question in an answer?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230676/please-post-your-answers-as-answers-not-comments/296481#296481  (...and using zero-or-more quantifiers doesn't feel like a good idea)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use *regular expressions* to match and group parts of the string that you want to work with.

In your case you can use a regular expression like `/(?<=\ )(\d+)\*(\d+)$/` to match and group the product height and product width from a given product name string (according to your product naming pattern):

```php
<?php

// Some example product name strings
$productNames = [];
$productNames[] = '10MM BRONZE FLOAT 321*225';
$productNames[] = '10MM CLEAR FLOAT 366*244';
$productNames[] = '10MM CLEAR FLOAT 321*225';

$pattern = '/(?<=\ )(\d+)\*(\d+)$/';

foreach($productNames as $productName) {
    $matches = [];
    preg_match($pattern, $productName, $matches);
    $productHeight = $matches[1] ?? null;
    $productWidth = $matches[2] ?? null;
    if (false === is_numeric($productHeight)) {
        // handle invalid product name pattern
        continue;
    }
    if (false === is_numeric($productWidth)) {
        // handle invalid product name pattern
        continue;
    }
    $productSize = (int) $productHeight * (int) $productWidth;
    // Do something with the calculated product size
}
```

Comment: This answer is working unnecessarily hard.  See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can explode string with space delimeter and then explode result string with star delimeter. And finally multiply numbers.

Like:

```
$txt = '10MM BRONZE FLOAT 321*225';
 $exploded = explode(' ', $txt);
 $exploded2 = explode('*', $exploded[count($exploded-1)]);
 $result = intval($exploded2[0]) * intval($exploded2[1]);
```

Comment: Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: array - int in

Answer (score 0):

Jeroen's answer is doing unnecessary things.  There is no need to use coalescing operators if `preg_match()` is checked for a successful match.  The pattern also guarantees that the two matches will be numeric (`\d+` does precisely that).

Instead, I recommend this very simple snippet.  Essentially, capture the two integer values at the end of the string which are separated by `*`, then cast those strings as integer-type values before multiplying them.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/BYtfb))

```
$productNames= [
    '10MM BRONZE FLOAT 321*225',
    '10MM CLEAR FLOAT 366*244',
    '10MM CLEAR FLOAT boo*225'
];

foreach ($productNames as $productName) {
    if (!preg_match('~(\d+)\*(\d+)$~', $productName, $match)) {
        echo "could not extract dimensions from product name";
    } else {
        echo (int) $match[1] * (int) $match[2];
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
72225
89304
could not extract dimensions from product name
```

Comment: The performance gained by your alternative is insignificant. I purposely wrote my snippet the way I did because I favor verbosity and robustness over performance, especially when working with traditionally hard to read regular expressions. All subject to opinion and such, but felt I had to elaborate as to why I added those "unnecessary things".

Comment: My solution is not only performant, it is more direct and elegant.  I can't see any argument for why anyone would use your snippet over mine.  Your `continue` outcomes will NEVER be reached so they are useless lines of code. The lookbehind and the unnecessarily-escaped space character are also reasonably removed from the pattern.